# How to use html5 geolocation in the background for java web application

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, geolocation

I have googled around attempting to find an answer to this question, but I have had no luck so I will ask it hear in the hopes that one of you can help!

I am attempting the use the javascript method navigator.geolocation.watchPosition to continuously gather location data.

The scenario is that I have a java web application using servlets and jsps, and I would like to begin geolocation collection when the user logs in, and stop when the user logs out. The data would be uploaded to a sql database after being collected. I have successfully been able to collect data for a single page, but I don't know how to implement a solution that works across all pages in the application.

I appreciate any and all help, thanks!

Comment: what specific problems are you having? Why are multiple pages any different than a single page?

Comment: For the single page, the javascript is executing in the jsp and sending the data to the servlet for upload to the database. If you click to go to another page, the javascript stops executing and you are no longer collecting and uploading the data. I am trying to find a solution which can be implemented in the background, allowing the user to fully navigate the site while still collecting and uploading location data.

Comment: You need the same script in other pages. javascript has no persistence between page loads

Comment: I do not think that would be a viable solution given the size of this project. Is there not a way to create a separate background thread which runs the relevant javascript during the session?

Comment: no...there is not without using something like a browser extension which isn't very practical in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing a Java web application, I would suggest

1. Extract the JS logic that tracks user location from the JSP page, into a separate JS file or JSP file (if the script is generated dynamically).
2. Use a Servlet filter to add a reference to this tracking JS file into all HTML pages returned to client. You may use Regular Expression to search in the HTML content, insert `<script src="url to tracking JS file">` right before `</head>` tag.

The filter doesn't need to inject this script reference if it finds current user hasn't logged in yet.